# Windows software with no need for graphic viewer to explore WFS service?

Tags: wfs, software-recommendations

The city of Haarlem (Netherlands) publishes all its open data through a [WFS service](https://wfs.haarlem.nl/ows?service=WFS&version=2.0.0&request=GetCapabilities). To examine if I can build an interesting application with it I would like to explore the data this service produces.

What I am looking for is software similar to generic SOAP clients, that lets me:

- point to the service endpoint
- select an operation
- input request parameters
- perform a request
- show the response data

I have tried QGIS, but a fresh install of the current version produces an error about a missing qgis_core.dll. And I am not sure QGIS can do what I want, since I am not interested in visualizing the data at this moment.

I don't need a graphic viewer, but something that shows the actual requests and responses because I want to find out how to communicate with such a service in my own code.

Comment: There is an [SE group devoted to software recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) but they are off-topic here at GIS SE.

Comment: @Vince: I didn't expect much response for such specific requirements in the software recommendation group. But I might give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

The demo application that gets installed together with GeoServer might be rather good for your purpose. It works with all WFS services, not only your own installation.

[image]

Comment: It looks promising, but from what I see is that I have to interpret the responses to build new requests. I hoped I didn't have to do that, but that the software would interpret the response of a getCapabilities request and present a user interface to let me pick operations using the parameters as described by the service.

Comment: I guess that you would like to find something like another GeoServer demo application, WCS request builder. I am not aware of anything like that. Closest that I know is the WFS client in GeoExplorer (part or OpenGEO suite) and Kosmo GIS v. 3.0 RC1. With those you must log the requests and responses from the http traffic for seeing what really happens. OpenJUMP Plus, gwSIG and perhaps Gaia GIS client may be worth a try as well. QGIS can only build BBOX filters but no advanced spatial filters or attribute filters so it is not so good for learning.